# Linking button action on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following code to remove an item from a list on AngularJS:

```
$scope.removeItem = function() {
  if($scope.items.indexOf(toDelete) > -1) {
    var index = $scope.items.indexOf(toDelete);
    $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
  }
};
```

And the following code in my jade template:

```
  div.row.spacing-small(ng-repeat='item in items')
    div.col-lg-4: p {{item}}
    div.col-lg-2: button.btn.btn-danger.btn-block Delete
```

The items object is basically an array, like this: ['foo', 'bar']. Is there a way to connect the "Delete" button with the removeItem function? I am still playing around with this fantastic framework but it is all just so new that it's hard sometimes to find the right thing in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
div.row.spacing-small(ng-repeat='item in items')
    div.col-lg-4: p {{item}}
    div.col-lg-2: button.btn.btn-danger.btn-block(ng-click=\"removeItem($index)\")


$scope.removeItem = function(index) {
    $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
};
```

This should help

**UPDATED**

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/8ydBU/)**

Answer (score 0):

I would use the ng-click directive and call removeItem(item).  Since you are doing an ng-repeat, each repeated block will have the correct item reference.  Also, I've found that when calling functions from ng-repeat, it is easiest to make the function take a reference to the object it should modify.